Contents of ISO packages
I've servers that have no internet connection, so i downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 ISO files and mount them. Mount is done successfully, i can list the contents in the mounted directory.
My aim is to install ntp and apt-mirror packages but i got "unable to locate package" error for both.
Did I do a mistake or is it normal that ISO doesn't contain these two packages? If normal, what is the best way to install required packages in an environment that has no internet connection.
Regards,
Yavuz

Your question says you are installing Ubuntu Core 22, as this is the only Ubuntu product that has a single version number. If this is not correct please edit the question and correct. The ISO needs to be installed somewhere to be able to extract working software.

The ISOs contain a squashfs system that is expanded onto your disk, and not packages that can be installed directly (that would make a larger ISO, and slow down installs rather extensively).  If you opt to do a minimal install; the standard approach was expand squashfs then remove the unwanted packages as it's faster.  Do note you didn't specify what 22 ISO; was it Ubuntu Core 22?  There is some variation of ISOs with >24 22.04 ISOs, available for various architectures & respins; so some variation can exist

if the servers are not connected and you have a machine connected to those servers that does have internet have a look at puppetmaster. You use your desktop (master) as a machine to update those servers (puppet)

So as i understand from comments, it is normal that the ISO does not contain ntp and apt-mirror packages, right? @ArturMeinild
I have to try the methods from the link you shared?

"is it normal that ISO doesn't contain these two packages?" The Ubuntu installer images ("ISO") are not complete software libraries. they contain only enough to install the base system.
